# Examples of maps with nontrivial Hopf invariant but Lusternik-Schnirelmann category of the cofiber doesn't increase?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $A$ be a suspension and $X$ be a space with Lusternik-Schnirelmann category $n$ and let $\alpha: A\to X$.  It is easy to see that the cofiber $C_\alpha$ has $\mathrm{cat}(C_\alpha) \leq n+1$. One of the standard ways to decide if $\mathrm{cat}(C_\alpha)$ is actually equal to 
$n+1$ is to look at the Berstein-Hilton-Hopf invariants $H_\sigma(\alpha)$
for the various structure maps $\sigma:X\to G_n(X)$ witnessing the 
inequality $\mathrm{cat}(X)\leq n$.  If $H_\sigma(\alpha) = *$ for any $\sigma$, 
then $\mathrm{cat}(C_\alpha) \leq n$.

I know that examples are exist to show that the converse implication 
is false, but my list is very short: in fact, it is limited to the paper
`Cogroups which are not suspensions' by Berstein and Harper (LNM 1370).

Question/Request:  Other examples of this phenomenon, especially references to examples in print.